# How to set PATH on MacOs for non-login shell?

Tags: macos, ssh, shell, path, sshd

On mac os, if I do `ssh localhost 'md5sum --version'` the `md5sum` command located in `/usr/local/bin` is not found.

This path is listed in `/etc/paths` but this config file is not read by the shell because the command above creates a non-login shell, so the shell expects the caller to have already set up the `PATH`

How do you update the `PATH` value to include `/usr/local/bin` in that case?

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: I use fish but that shouldn't be shell dependant. the ssh server should setup correctly the PATH for me right?

Answer (score 0):

**some explanations:**

I can't find any common place to set PATH for all non-login shells in macOS. maybe there is not any? :(

for example, this article explain some solution to set path for process started by launchD (not usable for non-login ssh sessions) :

https://lucaspin.medium.com/where-is-my-path-launchd-fc3fc5449864

but for your usecase, with a non-login ssh session, I tried this on macOS Sonoma:

```
ssh localhost 'echo $PATH'
```

which return this output:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

where this PATH came from? look at /etc/ssh/sshd_config file, see comments in the first few lines (last below line) :

```
#       $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.104 2021/07/02 05:11:21 dtucker Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

sshd **was compiled** with that PATH